# VBA: Retrieve data from a filter and store it in a variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables, filter

I have a filter on the column heading "Area" which when applied shows only the records where the area matches the filter applied, e.g. 5.

**Is there a piece of code that stores the value from the filter in a variable?**

The code the filter uses is:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$BN$197").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=
```

So what I want is something like:

```
dim Filter As String
Filter = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$BN$197").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=
```

But the problem is because it is a filter, the area filtering on can change, i.e. one user may filter on area 5 whilst another on area 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you want something like this:

```
Dim ftr                   As Filter
Dim sCriterion            As String
Set ftr = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(2)
If ftr.On Then sCriterion = Mid$(ftr.Criteria1, 2)
```

as long as you **know** they will only have filtered on one value. Otherwise you need to check the `Operator` and then determine what sort of filter is in place.

For an automatic event code, you could use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim ftr                   As Filter
On Error Goto hell
Set ftr = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(2)
If ftr.On Then
   application.enableevents = False
   debug.print ftr.criteria1
   Range("E205").value = Mid$(ftr.Criteria1, 2)
End If

hell:
   application.enableevents = true
End Sub
```

Right-click the worksheet tab, choose *View Code* and then paste that in.

Comment: Thank you! That works, I'm getting it so that it then displays the value in a cell, so beneath your code I have added the following: `Range("E205").Select`
`ActiveCell.Value = sCriterion` But this will only work when I run the macro, is there a way of getting the code to run automatically when the filter is applied?

Comment: If you have any subtotal formulas in place, you can use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event to update the filter criteria.

Comment: I don't have any subtotal formulas, but can you show me how I would use `Wordsheet_Calculate` to automatically run the macro when a filter is applied?

Comment: Ok, so just to make sure I've got this correct, I make a new module and then insert the code: `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim ftr                   As Filter

Set ftr = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(2)
If ftr.On Then Range("E205").value = Mid$(ftr.Criteria1, 2)
End Sub` into the module, then when I apply a filter the value will be displayed in E205? is this correct?

Comment: No - it goes in the worksheet code module - see the last line of the answer.

Comment: Ok, that works! But I get this error come up in a pop up: Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed

Comment: I've amended the code. If you still get an error please tell me what is output to the immediate window in the VB Editor as the filter criterion.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but is it possible to do this for multiple filters? So as well as having this work for the area I also want it to work for the region?

Comment: Yes - just repeat the code and change the filter number and target cell.